# How to determine which binary is generated upon bitbaking a recipe

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, embedded-linux, yocto, bitbake

I'm trying to build a specific recipe after making changes to a source file but I can't seem to figure out which binary it's supposed to generate.

```
$ poky/build rebake <recipe-name>

$ cd /tmp-glibc/deploy/images/msm8909-quec-smart/
$ ls
  msm8909-boot.img  msm8909-boot.img.nonsecure  vmlinux
```

But the directory with source files isn't a part of the `kernel` folder so I'm unsure as to why it would generate the boot image.

I also tried running `oe-pkgdata-util list-pkgs <recipe-name>`, and it only outputted `<recipe-name>`.

Is there any way to determine which binary/image the building of a recipe generates?

Edit:

Similar to how `rebake virtual/kernel` generates boot.img, but where's it defined `virtual/kernel` will generate boot.img?

Comment: Is the recipe written by you?

Comment: no. it's a part of the git project that I cloned.